# as query not supporting in cosmos db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying following code to get details but it is not return what i want .

my query :

```html
   var query = $"SELECT catalog.id as vendorguid,catalog.VendorName,industry.Id as industryguid,industry.IdustryId,industry.IdustryName,category.id as categoryguid,category.Name as categoryname,category.Description as categorydescription,Subcategory.Id as subcategoryguid,Subcategory.Name as subcategoryname,Subcategory.Description as subcategorydescription,product.Id as productguid,product.Name as productname,product.CurrentQuantity as productCurrentQuantity,product.Tag as productTag,product.ImageUrl as productImageUrl,product.Unit as productUnit,product.Price as productPrice,product.hasMethodOfPreparation as producthasMethodOfPreparation,product.MethodOfPreparation as productMethodOfPreparation,product.Addons as productAddons FROM catalogjoin industry in catalog.Industy join category in industry.Category join Subcategory in category.Subcategoryjoin product in Subcategory.Product where product.Id = '"+productId+"'";
```

my service class  :
[image]

output:

```html
{
      "id": "d91af3e6-6aae-4d10-9ba6-6b97ca4cd881",
      "vendorName": "string",
      "industy": []
    }
```

expected output:

```html
{
        "vendorguid": "97392a23-c8c4-4a7f-bffb-7c3807cc40de",
        "VendorName": "string",
        "industryguid": "f8265ee6-a351-4036-a0ee-10ec4f51ecf4",
        "IdustryId": 0,
        "IdustryName": "string",
        "categoryguid": "ce7edfdf-1608-4a8c-ae38-7ca60c43bc30",
        "categoryname": "string",
        "categorydescription": "string",
        "subcategoryguid": "709f4e6f-1bba-421f-8dc0-7cf067cbc032",
        "subcategoryname": "string",
        "subcategorydescription": "string",
        "productguid": "d24dd340-d7a2-42e5-b84a-1ee72d9840c6",
        "productname": "string",
        "productCurrentQuantity": 0,
        "productTag": "string",
        "productImageUrl": [
            "string"
        ],
        "productUnit": 0,
        "productPrice": 0,
        "producthasMethodOfPreparation": true,
        "productMethodOfPreparation": [               
        ],
        "productAddons": [              
        ]
    }
```

how can i get it anyone help me?

Comment: Can you run the query on Azure portal by using Data Explorer?

Comment: yes . it is returning the value in data explorer

Comment: now i correct it. please help me one the above please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is in your joins (Category, SubCategory). Are your sure its always finding a match? If it **doesn't** find a match or **don't have** that properties, CosmosDb will *not* include it in the results set.

Its not like the left join of MSSQL where nulls are included. CosmosDb is more of a full outer join (cross join).